# How to round to two digits the data of the table that shows the information of the pareto chart

Tags: highcharts, maps, stock

When displaying the data from the pareto chart in the table it shows it without rounding, I need it to stay in two digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit data visible in data-table by `exportData` callback function. For example:

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      exportData: function({ dataRows }) {
        dataRows.forEach((row, i) => {
          if (i > 1) { // skip headers
            row[1] = row[1].toFixed(2);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tzb430u8/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.exportData